# Effective calculation of cummulative binomial distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Given $X \sim B(n,p)$, calculate $P(X \leq k)$. This probability is noted as $F(k;n,p)$.

I search an effective method to calculate the cumulative binomial distribution, so it can be done with a nonprogrammable calculator in a reasonable time to a reasonable precision. I found an integral representation which contains the integral

$$\int_{0}^{1-p}t^{n-k-1}(1-t)^k dt,$$

but for large numbers $k$ and $n$, the derivations get very high, so for example Gauss-Legendre is not very precise or time-consuming. Is there an efficient method to calculate $F(k;n,p)$?

Comment: You could approximate it using the normal distribution assuming that is available on your calculator. The approximation if fairly reasonable when $np>5$ and $nq>5$.

Comment: Yes, but the precision is not overhelming unless p is very near 0,5. Can such an approximation be improved somehow (besides the continouity correction) ?

Comment: And no, my calculator does not have this function. I would have to approximate it.

Comment: I think it depends on what you are trying to do. de Casteljau's algorithm can minimize the number of redundant calculations you may need to perform. Similarly, using the tabular method may make the integration by parts much faster, but if it is in the context of an exam, I don't think you would need to do anything special beyond maybe using $1-P(X>k) = P(X\leq k)$.

I should add that I do not actually endorse using de Casteljau's algorithm just to speed up hand calculations as that was not the intended purpose.